WSL1: Permission denied during apt
After working with WSL for about a year, I am suddenly experiencing permission problems.
sudo su
(base) root@...:/mnt# apt-get update && apt-get install jq
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:4 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

(base) root@...:/mnt# sudo dpkg --configure -a
> dpkg: error: error installing new file '/var/lib/dpkg/status': Permission denied

(base) root@...:/mnt# whoami
> root

(base) root@...:/mnt# ls -alh /var/lib/dpkg/status
> -rw-r--r-- 2 root root 0 Jun 26 08:35 /var/lib/dpkg/status

I have added the usual configurations to wsl.conf, but no change:
[automount]
root = /
# options = "metadata"
options  = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11,uid=1000,gid=1000"

This also appears to be somewhat randomly, as sometimes (once a week), I can do apt installs without problems.
I tried exporting and re-importing the distro with lxrunoffline:
LxRunOffline.exe export -n UF -f c:/temp/UF.tar.gz
LxRunOffline.exe install -n UF2 -d c:/wsl/UF2 -f c:/temp/UF.tar.gz

But even after importing, the problem persists in the new installation.
Any help appreciated.

I've seen this error a lot myself within the last year, though I'm on WLS2. The best I have managed is a collection of "try this and try that" answers, but don't have enough information about why permission is denied in the first place to know when to apply a given solution.
